# Problema con foreach y datagridview c#

Tags: c#, foreach, datagridview

Hola que tal una consulta.

Estoy metiendome en el mundo de programacion en C#. Quiero guardar varias filas de un datagridview en Sql, estoy usando C# y SQL Server.

Estuve viendo algunos post similares en esta misma pagina pero no me esta saliendo.

Tengo este codigo:

```
public String CargarDetalle()
        {
            bool rta = false;
            String sql = "INSERT INTO DetalleVenta (idProducto, idVenta, Costo) VALUES (@idProducto, @idVenta, @Costo)";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = MiBD; Integrated Security = True"))
               foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dgv.Rows)

                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idProducto", idProducto);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idVenta", idVenta);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Costo", Costo);
                    rta = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
                    con.Close();
                }return "";}
```

Y en la tabla en vez de que guarden los 2 productos distintos, se guarda solo el primero y duplicado:

[image: Venta guardada]

Estoy seguro que el problema es donde esta el foreach, pero lo probe en varios lados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se produce porque estás asignando a los parámetros del `SqlCommand` unas variables (`idProducto`, `idVenta`, `Costo`) cuyos valores no cambian dentro del `foreach`.

En el siguiente ejemplo se asume que las columnas del `DataGridView` que contienen los valores que se insertarán son las siguientes:

```
int columnaIdProducto = 0;
int columnaIdVenta = 1;
int columnaCosto = 2;
```

Ten en cuenta que los nombres de estas variables los puedes cambiar según te convenga y debes asignarle los valores de las columnas reales.

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public String CargarDetalle()
{
    bool rta = false;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO DetalleVenta (idProducto, idVenta, Costo) VALUES (@idProducto, @idVenta, @Costo)";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = MiBD; Integrated Security = True"))
    {
        // Coloca la apertura y cierre de la base de datos fuera del foreach
        con.Open();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dgv.Rows)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            //                                         | así asignas los valores de cada celda
            //                                         V
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idProducto", fila.Cells[columnaIdProducto].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idVenta", fila.Cells[columnaIdVenta].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Costo", fila.Cells[columnaCosto].Value);
            rta = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
        }
        con.Close();
        return "";}
    }
}
```

Es importante destacar que al no tener la información del tipo de datos de los parámetros, es posible que se requiera algún tipo de conversión al asignar el valor de cada celda a los parámetros.

Comment: Podes evitar crear el comando en cada vuelta (es innecesario la reasignacion), lo que si, si haces eso, entonces tenes que limpiar los parametros en cada vuelta...

Comment: Pablo, te has ganado mi respeto. Muchas gracias